# HBase filter to match every row that contains a string

Tags: filter, hbase

I want to retrieve all rows that contain a string in a column family. The ValueFilter sort of gives me what I need, except that it only returns the columns that contain the string. The SingleColumnValueFilter is also close, except that it requires a qualifier to be provided which would be the only one checked for the presence of the string. What I need is a combination of these two, which is a filter that checks for the string in all the columns in a particular column family, and returns the entire row, if a match is found. Is that available in HBase 0.90.0? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can user filters for each column qualifiers , provided the number of column qualifiers are within reasonable limits. After creating filters, create a FilterList object passing the parameter for 'OR' operation.

FilterList fList = new FilterList(Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE);